# Java - Compressed Image size is bigger than original (BufferedImage)

Tags: java, bufferedimage

I'm trying to compress an image to upload to S3 Bucket but after the image is compressed, the size of the compressed image is larger than the original. From 227KB -> 236KB
Can anybody explain for me why this happened?

Here's my code:

```java
 BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(photoFile);
 File compressedImageFile = new File("compressed_image.jpeg");
 OutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(compressedImageFile);

 Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpeg");
 ImageWriter imageWriter = writers.next();

 ImageOutputStream imageOutputStream =  ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputStream);
 imageWriter.setOutput(imageOutputStream);

 ImageWriteParam imageWriteParam = imageWriter.getDefaultWriteParam();

  if (imageWriteParam.canWriteCompressed()) {
                    imageWriteParam.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
  imageWriteParam.setCompressionQuality(0.5f);
  }
    imageWriter.write(null, new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null), imageWriteParam);

  log.info("Close stream");
  outputStream.close();
  imageOutputStream.close();
  imageWriter.dispose();
```

Here's my image:
[original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vZ8MQ.jpg) - 227KB
[compressed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39cAF.jpg) - 236KB

I tried to change the compression quality but it doesn't seem working, and this problem happens in some case, not all

Comment: Wrap your closable resources like writers/IO streams in try-with-resources blocks

Comment: "I tried to change the compression quality but it doesn't seem working,": if you try with quality factor less than 0.5 it will definitely reduce the size. so your image is at around 0.5 no visible change in the compressed image is there? So definittely you can bring the size down - e.g. if you compress with 0.1 DID YOU TRY THAt?

Comment: Yes, I if I change the quality factor below 0.5 the size of the image is smaller but I'm wondering why the size of the compressed image when the factor is >= 0.5 is larger than the original photo @gpasch

Answer (score 1):

jpeg images are already compressed. “Compressing” an already compressed file makes it a bit bigger (header data) each time.

A text file on the other hand will get much smaller.

Comment: I'm not sure it's accurate to say "header data" causes larger file size.  (JFIF files have a short header.)  Perhaps it's that the Huffman coding of the coefficients is less efficient after multiple compressions?

Comment: it's definitely incorrect.